# How to get all keys with maximum value no built in

Tags: python

I have a task to get keys with maximum values. What I have now works except for when the max appears more than once. So, for example {a:2,b:1,c:2} right now this returns just a but I need it to return both a and c. I know there are question like this already but I need it to NOT have any built in functions
Here's the code I already have:

```
    maximum = 0
    result = []
    max_key = None
    for i in scores:
        value = scores[i]
        if value > maximum:
            maximum = scores[i]
            max_key = i
    return max_key
```

Answer (score 5):

Hint: You need to loop over the scores twice: once to get the max value, and a second time to get all of the keys with that value.

Comment: Literally was about to post the same thing, but you got there first.

Comment: I did it only looping once?

Comment: Fair enough. I'd argue that the two-loop solution is more understandable, but I suppose you don't *need* to have two loops.

Comment: See also my comment regarding the complexity (time and space) on answer by @BeRT2me, which was prompted in response to performance analysis by BeRT2me. In a word, the double loop may be less prone to using more space than is needed, and there are score sequences where single looping is slower. That said, the single looping solution is clever.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```py
scores = {'a':2,'b':1,'c':2}
high = None
for score in scores.values():
    if high is None or score > high:
        high = score
keys = [k for k, v in scores.items() if v == high]
print(keys)
```

First loop finds the maximum (without using the built-in `max()` function). Then, a list comprehension collects all keys in the input `scores` with value matching the maximum.

Comment: 484 ns ± 8.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

Iterates through dict, replacing results if new max found, and adding index to results if same max found.

```
def fancy_max(scores):
    maximum = 0
    for i in scores:
        value = scores[i]
        if value > maximum:
            maximum = value
            result = [i]
        elif value == maximum:
            result.append(i)
    return result

s = {'a':2,'b':1,'q':5, 'c':2, 'd':4, 'j':5}
out = fancy_max(s)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['q', 'j']
```

Comment: 366 ns ± 1.84 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Comment: Though the question does not specifically address performance, it's intriguing that your solution can outperform others depending on the input. For example, please run your speed comparison for either of the following inputs: `s = {'a' + str(i):5 for i in range(100)} | {'b':6}` or `scores = {'a' + str(i):5 + i // 20 for i in range(100)} | {'b':6}`. I think you will find that an overall maximum near the end of the input dict can disadvantage your solution. Also, worst-case space complexity will be higher for yours than one that only builds the list after max is known.

Comment: That is an interesting phenomenon, also, swapping my `if/elif` statements leads to a performance boost on your suggested inputs. - still not quite as good as your method though.

Comment: On those longer ones, if the dict is sorted in reverse order (highest to lowest), our two methods perform almost exactly the same, but if they're (lowest to highest) mine does suffer a performance boost.